# pg_dump version mismatch in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, postgresql-9.1, pg-dump

When running the `rake db:structure:dump` command, I encountered the following error:

```
Larson-2:app larson$ rake db:structure:dump
pg_dump: server version: 9.1.3; pg_dump version: 9.0.4
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
rake aborted!
Error dumping database
```

How can I go about updating pg_dump? I have pg 9.1.3 installed, is there a way to update the references inside of Rails to the new version?

When I try to update postgres via homebrew, I get the following output:

```
Larson-2:app larson$ sudo brew upgrade postgresql
Password:
Error: postgresql already upgraded
```

Comment: use a pg_dump of version 9.1.3 instead

Comment: What does `pg_config --bindir` say?

Comment: @francs how can i set pg_dump to a new version? it is called by the rake task

Comment: @dbenhur `pg_config --bindir`
`/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.4/bin`

Comment: so you have brew install of pg 9.0. uninstall it and replace with pg 9.1

Comment: When I do `brew upgrade postgresql` I get an error: `Error: postgresql already upgraded`

Comment: Oh dear, I ran into this issue as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800527/homebrew-install-permissions-issue

Comment: I resolved the above issue but it appears that homebrew can only install 9.0.4 and not the later versions. Not sure why.

Comment: My issue was that the mac osx comes with this. I had two versions installed and they were conflicting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I resolved the issue, first update homebrew:

`brew update`
if you get this error: `error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:`

then:

```
cd /usr/local/cellar
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

After you finish updating homebrew: 
`sudo brew install postgresql` 
 
Which will install 9.1.3 (or the most current version of pg) and any dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

on my machine, the problem was with the PATH. there was a pg_dump v. 9.0.10 on /usr/bin and my server was 9.1.something.

Changing the path to make /usr/local/Cellar/postgres/9..../bin (or whatever is the path to the actual postgres installation you use) come before anything else worked like a breeze. I only had to re-open any open terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Followed the postgres command-line Tools documentation, then had to run `rake db:reset` then `rake db:test:prepare` to copy my test database over. After I did those things, it worked.