# There is no Cellar file in my usr/local dir for brew

Tags: homebrew, macos-high-sierra

I have been trying to use brew to install tmux but every time I put in `brew install tmux` it would tell me:

> Error: Could not create /usr/local/Cellar Check you have permission to write to /usr/local

I then tried to do it with sudo but it did not work, which I guest would would not seeing that brew does not want to be used with root. I have already made sure that all the files that are in /usr/local belong to me. I can’t change the /usr/local file; it says: “Operation not permitted”. How can I fix this so Cellar can be created and allow me to install stuff using brew?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I solved it by creating the /usr/local/Cellar directory (and any other directories it may require) by hand and owning them.

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/Cellar
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Cellar
```

Then rerun your command.

Answer (score 15):

i found mine also in

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar
```

mac m1(if this info helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I could not find this yet in the homebrew docs. Happy to have at least found it here.

Answer (score 7):

Before run any brew command do these steps:

```
1- $ brew update

2- brew doctor
```

3- If brew doctor shows the warning or error, just fix them , it also shows the solution and the command that you need so copy & paste the command & run it, that's simple

4- install what you need, for example node :

```
brew install node
```

Answer (score 5):

I found my Cellar directory in

> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/

Comment: This is the location on macOS Ventura for me as well. Things changed.

Comment: Same in Sonoma for me